# Understanding places where the Torah writes היא instead of הוא

Tags: safrus, avot-derabbi-natan

In most cases in the Torah, the feminine 2nd person word (equiv. to "she" or "her" in English) is written as  הוא using a ו and pronounced הִוא .

[Avot Derabbi Natan 42:5](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/34-2.htm) lists 11 places in the Torah where the word is written as היא with a yod. (Of notable interest is the 2nd verse that combines writing the word both with a vav, with a yod and the form with a vav used in the masculine form.)

Is there a reason why these situations are made the exceptions? Does anyone discuss a hidden meaning (Midrash, etc.) as to why this happens?

Comment: [Parallel question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27783/%d7%94%d7%95%d7%90-is-he-or-is-it).

Comment: @rish Hmmm ... I have to digest that one a bit. It has a lot of info, but, right now I don't know if it sufficiently answers my question.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't suggesting (and don't think) that it's a duplicate; that question is about the broader phenomenon of writing הוא in place of היא, whereas this question asks about the exceptions where the Torah _doesn't_ spell it that way.